# Prove: $C-(A\cup B)=(C-A)\cap (C-B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please help review this part of the proof.

Suppose that $x\in C-(A\cup B)$. Therefore, $x\in C$ and $x\notin (A \cup B)$. Then, $x\in C \wedge (x\notin A \wedge x\notin B)$. By morgan laws we got that $x\in C \wedge x\notin A$ and $x\in C \wedge x\notin B$. By definition of set subtraction $x\in C-A \wedge x\in C-B$ By intersection definition is clear that $x\in (C-A) \cap (C-B)$. Therefore, $C-(A\cup B)\subset (C-A)\cap (C-B)$.

The other part $ (C-A)\cap (C-B) \subset C-(A\cup B)$ is pretty much similar.

Comment: Haven't read on yet, but just as a heads up, "If $C-(A\cup B)$" isn't a valid premise. It would be more accurate to just replace the first sentence with, "Let $x$ be an element of $C-(A\cup B)$, then $x\in C$ ..."

Comment: I think this is true. For other part you can put _if and only if_ between the first part statements.

Comment: When you say 'by morgan laws' you are actually using distribution

Comment: Noted, thank you @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of your argument is correct, though the wording needs polishing.

You *have* proceeded by using (1) the definition of set difference, (2) de Morgan's Law on complement of a union, (3) distribution, (4) the definition of set difference, then finally (5) the definition of union.   Since each step is biconditional, that is all you need to do.

> $${\def\getsto{\mathop{\leftrightarrow}}\begin{align}\because~x\in C\smallsetminus (A\cup B)~&\getsto~(x\in C~\wedge~x\notin(A\cup B)) \tag 1 \\&\getsto~ (x\in C~\wedge~(x\notin A~\wedge~x\notin B)) \tag 2 \\&\getsto~((x\in C\wedge x\notin A)\wedge(x\in C\wedge x\notin B)) \tag 3\\ & \getsto~(x\in (C\smallsetminus A)~\wedge~x\in (C\smallsetminus B)) \tag 4\\ &\getsto~x\in (C\smallsetminus A)\cap (C\smallsetminus B) \tag 5  \\\hline\therefore\quad C\smallsetminus (A\cup B)~&=~~(C\smallsetminus A)\cap(C\smallsetminus B)\end{align}}$$

So just polish up your wordsmithing.

---

> An arbitrary element will be an element of the set $C\smallsetminus (A\cup B)$ exactly when it is an element of $C$ but not of either $A$ nor $B$.   So any such element of our set is exactly an element of $C$, not an element of $A$, *and* not an element of $B$.   Thus $C\smallsetminus (A\cup B)$ is *equal* to $(C\smallsetminus A)\cap(C\smallsetminus B)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$C\setminus (A\cup B)= {C\cap (A\cup B)^c}_{\text{intersection with a set complement when U defined}}=C\cap(A^c\cap B^c)=$$$$=C\cap (A^c\cap B^c)\cap C=(C\cap A^c)\cap (C\cap B^c)=(C\setminus A)\cap (C\setminus B)$$
$$Q.E.D.$$